# Set height of floated elements to 100% of the browser window

Tags: css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <section>
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
             Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
    </section>
    <section></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #0f0;
}
body:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
body > section:first-of-type {
  width: 300px;
  background: #f00;
  float: left;
}
body > section:last-of-type {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00f;
  float: right;
}
```

Also, here's the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/f9usmbkv/

As you can see from the example, section on the right is set at 100% height, but it doesn't match the height of the browser window, so can I make both sections have 100% height of the browser window and not the 100% height of body element?

Can I do this only with CSS or do I have to use JavaScript?

Update:

I had a similar question asked not a while ago:
[Set height of floated elements to 100% of the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744215/set-height-of-floated-elements-to-100-of-the-browser-window/)

However, for this project using display:flex is out of the question, since I have to support browsers that don't use it yet, but have a look at that question, it might help you.

Comment: look up vh and vw measurements

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f9usmbkv/1/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @knitevision No, I just want blue section and red section to have 100% height of the green area, in my example body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternative to using tables is using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var docH = $(document).height();
    console.log(docH);
    $('.right-col').height(docH-8);
});
```

heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9usmbkv/6/ . the 8 is to offset the padding on the body.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the approach you'd like to use, but this approach works: using tables

css:

```
.table { 
    display: table; 
    width:100%;
}
.table section { 
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 100vw - 600px; 
    padding: 10px; 
}
.table section:nth-child(even) { 
    background: #ccc;
}
.table section:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: #eee;
}

<body>
  <div class="table">
    <section style="background:red; width:300px;">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum     </section>
    <section></section>
    <section style="background:blue; width:300px;"></section>
  </div>
</body>
```

heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9usmbkv/5/

Comment: This is the closest thing that I was going for. I'm not too keen on tables though, but I don't think there's any other way to do it.

Comment: @Mentalhead - there is alternative. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a css-reset. Elements have intrinsic margins and paddings. Hence the space around your sections. By doing a reset you start with a clean slate. Also, doing a `box-sizing` will ensure that the widths are calculated taking margins and borders into account cross-browser.

And then set `overflow:hidden` on body and `overflow:auto` on your `section`s.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    background: #0f0;
}
body:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
body > section:first-of-type {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f00;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
body > section:last-of-type {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #00f;
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </section>
<section></section>
```

Comment: Not sure the OP is going to want that vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I was going for, I don't want vertical scroll bar. I just want to both sections to fill 100% of the browser window.

Comment: @Mentalhead: Did you run that snippet in full-screen? There is a link on the top-right corner which says "Full page". Click that and see. And without scrollbar, how will you access the contents that overflow in your section?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that the way you think about it (not by using height:100% property). But there is a workaround called "**Faux Columns**" which is kind of visual way of achieving effect you want.
This article [here](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) written by Dan Cederholm, describes this technique and might be help to you.

Generally - you are specifying a background image on the parent element which is then repeated on y axis. This creates an *impression* of two equally tall columns. The aim here is to prepare right image, knowing the width of your columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use Grace Lee answer or try with Flexbox:

```
body {
    margin: 0
}

.flex-outside {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-inside {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 2;
}

.left {flex: none; background-color: red;}
.center {flex: auto; background-color:green;}
.right {flex: none; background-color: blue;}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyt3kbfs/)